# How To Check If An Oscilloscope Is DC Capable

Tags: oscilloscope, datasheet, waveform, specifications

I am busy working on some analogue synthesizers at the moment and just got the hang of OP-amp to some degree. I want to invest in a decent Oscilloscope something like 50Mhz-100Mhz.

So based on advice 50Mhz+ (Ray Wilson Make: Analogue Synthesizers), should be fine however apparently it needs to be DC capable. I was looking at a potentially buying [a Hantek DSO5102P](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Hantek-DSO5102P-Digital-Oscilloscope-2-Channels-100MHz-1GSa-s-Like-SDS1102CNL-/182401298376?hash=item2a77f6efc8:g:gNQAAOxyTjNSmD5T) which appears to tick most of the boxes.

However I cant find anything saying it is DC capable. So I started viewing other scopes and found similar problems. They do not explicitly state they can handle DC which left me confused. How do I read a scopes specifications to ensure it is DC capable?

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen an oscilloscope that was AC-only...?

Comment: If you try to use a soundcard as a scope you might run into a DC block.  Or is the question about *powering* the scope from DC for portability or line isolation?

Comment: New to purchasing oscilloscope so not sure what to look for to get a DC capable scope. Just want to make sure I am not throwing money on the fire. Is it DC capable?

Comment: @Namphibian Do you mean that it can graph DC input or that it can be powered from a DC power source.

Comment: Measure DC. Most specs mention which I assume means they can but I can't work on assumptions. Just need to make sure it can measure DC. My scope knowledge is a daiper stage.

Comment: Yes it's DC capable....in the overview sheet it shows the DC gain of the unit. This shows it's DC capability from 2 mV per division  to 5 V per division (ie its input attenuator). Your *10 probe will take this to 50 V per division.

Comment: @JackCreasey thanks I assumed it would but need confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of a scope being sold that doesn't support DC coupling.

Generally when trying to figure out what features a device supports look for a User-manual, if you can't find a user manual look for other documentation like a datasheet, service manual etc. The information most likely will be in there.

In the case of your scope I found.

http://www.hantek.com/Product/Datasheet/DSO5000P_Datasheet.pdf

And as expected I found

Input Coupling AC, DC, GND

So yes it does support measuring DC inputs.